# Tomcat log files on OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat, logging

So, Tomcat 8 installed under /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.30 on OS X El Cap. I'm trying to figure out how to get logging to work.

I keep getting this message:

log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [/var/tomcat/common/classes/log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/tomcat/common/classes/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)

Which is frustrating me because that isn't even where Tomcat is even installed, so why the heck is it looking there for the log4j.properties file?

I installed Tomcat in /usr/local/lib following directions on the web (https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat8/) and put a log4j.properties file in the lib directory as instructed.

Additionally, I have a per application log4j file in WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml (in a war file),

but that doesn't work either. I keep getting:

log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [/var/tomcat/common/classes/log4j.properties]. NOTE: What the heck is this path? There is no such directory?!
log4j:WARN Large window sizes are not allowed.
log4j:WARN MaxIndex reduced to 13.
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ucsc/sczlogs/debug_log.txt (No such file or directory)

The last message line is reasonable enough, except I've changed that path everywhere I can think of to a reasonable location (desktop), but even though I restart Tomcat and clear out the work directory, I keep getting the same error message. I would go further and figure out where my application is and check to see what the log4j path is there, but I can't find it! It's not in /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.30/webapps, like I would think it would be.

Sorry if this is something stupid, but I've been looking at this for hours and I can't figure out how to get log files out of this thing, which I desperately need to do to figure out what the heck is going on in my program and my struggle to get an AJAX form to work. BTW, I installed all this on Linux on the production server and it makes sense. I don't know what is up with OS X and Tomcat. Thanks!

Comment: I think the trouble has something to do with the way Eclipse is starting Tomcat. When I start it by command line, I get a CATALINA_HOME that makes sense and logging works. When I start it via Eclipse, I get some weird path for where it is trying to put the log files, and by weird, I mean a directory that doesn't exist. So I assume that Eclipse is overriding the correct CATALINA_HOME and substituting some other path. I'm trying to figure out how to change that with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

when you start up tomcat append the following to the startup

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/PATH/TO/log4j.properties
```